# Notifications on Slack with Symfony and Monolog

Tags: php, notifications, symfony4, slack-api, monolog

I'm here to ask for new help.
Problem: with each exception, I have to send a message on Slack provided that the exception has not already been notified in the previous minute (no notifications from 404 errors).
Symfony version: 4.3
I thought of taking advantage of Monolog's SlackHandler. Here is what I did.

**monolog.yaml**

```
monolog:
    channels: ['notifier']
```

**prod/monolog.yaml**

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        slack_errors:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            excluded_404s:
                - ^/
            handler: slack_errors_handler
        slack_errors_handler:
            type: slack
            token: '%app.exception_notifier.slack.token%'
            channel: '%app.exception_notifier.slack.channel%'
            bot_name: '%app.exception_notifier.slack.bot%'
            icon_emoji: ':ghost:'
            level: critical
            include_extra: true
            channels: ['notifier']
```

I created an entity to save the exception on the database (entity's properties: class of the generating event, exception code, exception message, exception trace), and I prepersist the creation date. I also have a property that identifies whether the entity has been notified or not.
With a simple query of the database I check if I have already notified the exception in the last 60 seconds.
I created an exception subscriber, injecting an appropriate manager therein. So I do save the exception in the database and I check whether the notification occurred in the previous 60 seconds.
Now, in case there have been no notifications, how do I take advantage of monolog with the above configuration?

This is the method that should dispatch the notification.

```php
/**
* @return bool
* @throws \Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException
* @throws \Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException
*/
public function dispatch()
{
    if ($this->log && ($id = $this->log->getId())) {
        if ($this->logRepository->findCountLogByExceptionEvent(
            $this->log, [$id], $this->interval
        )) {
            return false;
        }

        $this->logger->critical(); // @TODO
        $this->log->setIsNotified(1);
        $this->om->flush($this->log);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What to do with the `$this->logger->critical();` line, please?